# Vagrant startup times out on setup

Tags: centos, timeout, vagrant, virtualbox

I am doing this as part of the Ambari setup. followed the steps for [quick start](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Quick+Start+Guide) with Ambari and Vagrant.

I am using this CentOS 6.4 image:
https://github.com/u39kun/ambari-vagrant/blob/master/centos6.4/Vagrantfile

I did this on Google Cloud from RHEL 7.2 host and with VirtualBox 5, but went to install, as suggested, CentOS 6.4 guests.

I successfully installed and configured the pre-requisities (with tweaking required to make vbox 5 work on RHEL 7.2).

When I try to bring up 6 hosts, I see the timeouts where machines are not coming up.

Host machine I am running on is fast - 32 cores, 64 GB RAM, 500 GB SSD ...

Does anyone know what might be the issue? 
Is there some firewall I need to turn off, etc.?

```
[<myuser>@ambari-host-rhel7 centos6.4]$ ./up.sh 6
Bringing machine 'c6401' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> c6401: Box 'centos6.4' could not be found. Attempting to find and install... c6401: Box Provider: virtualbox c6401: Box Version: >= 0
==> c6401: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> c6401: Adding box 'centos6.4' (v0) for provider: virtualbox c6401: Downloading: http://developer.nrel.gov/downloads/vagrant-boxes/CentOS-6.4-x86_64-v20130427.box
==> c6401: Box download is resuming from prior download progress
==> c6401: Successfully added box 'centos6.4' (v0) for 'virtualbox'!
==> c6401: Importing base box 'centos6.4'...
==> c6401: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> c6401: Setting the name of the VM: centos64_c6401_1456171923223_2329
==> c6401: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> c6401: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration... c6401: Adapter 1: nat c6401: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> c6401: Forwarding ports... c6401: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> c6401: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> c6401: Booting VM...
==> c6401: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes... c6401: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222 c6401: SSH username: vagrant c6401: SSH auth method: private key


Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means thatVagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine withinthe configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) thatVagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errorsare usually good hints as to what may be wrong.If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properlyworking and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a commonproblem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,as well.If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increasethe timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

As a final step I get this summary error:

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrantfor controlling VirtualBox. 
The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["import", "/home/<me>/.vagrant.d/boxes/centos6.4/0/virtualbox/box.ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname", "CentOS-6.4-x86_64_1456173504674_45962", "--vsys", "0", "--unit", "9", "--disk", "/home/<me>/VirtualBox VMs/CentOS-6.4-x86_64_1456173504674_45962/box-disk1.vmdk"]
Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%

Interpreting /home/<me>/.vagrant.d/boxes/centos6.4/0/virtualbox/box.ovf...OK.0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERRORVBoxManage: error: Appliance import failedVBoxManage: error: Could not create the imported medium '/home/<me>/VirtualBox VMs/CentOS-6.4-x86_64_1456173504674_45962/box-disk1.vmdk'.
VBoxManage: error: VMDK: cannot write allocated data block in '/home/<me>/VirtualBox VMs/CentOS-6.4-x86_64_1456173504674_45962/box-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_DISK_FULL)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component ApplianceWrap, interface IAppliance
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleImportAppliance(HandlerArg*)" at line 877 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

Any ideas what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have free space on your drive ?

Generally `VERR_DISK_FULL` indicates that the hard drive is full, it cannot provision enough space for the vdi files.